# Making JSON from NSDictionary with the chars "_" and "/"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, couchdb

EDIT 2: I no longer think "_" and "/" in the dictionary keys are the problem.

EDIT 3: I don't think the JSON is the problem any more, or the HTTP POST request. I don't know exactly what it is yet.

EDIT 4: Solved it. The data element had to be valid base64, or else couch refuses it. Didn't know that. Can't select my own answer yet.

I have a dictionary I want to convert to a JSON string.
This is the setup of my dictionary:

```
- (NSDictionary*) createDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *room = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [room setObject:self.roomNumber forKey:@"roomNumber"];
    [room setObject:self.floor forKey:@"floor"];
    [room setObject:self.comment forKey:@"comment"];
    [room setObject:self.type forKey:@"type"];
    [room setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.status] forKey:@"status"];
    [room setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"_attachments"];

    NSMutableDictionary *attachments = [room objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@", @"attachments"]];
    [attachments setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"picture"];

    NSMutableDictionary *picture = [attachments objectForKey:@"picture"];
    [picture setObject:@"text/plain" forKey:@"content_type"];
    [picture setObject:@"BASE64" forKey:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"Room: %@", room);
    return room;
}
```

The problem is the "_" and "/" chars. When I print out the dictionary, it looks like this:

`Room: {
    "_attachments" =     {
        picture =         {
            "content_type" = "text/plain";
            data = BASE64;
        };
    };
    comment = 12;
    floor = 12;
    roomNumber = 12;
    status = 0;
    type = room;
}`

Don't know why it ends up on one line there, but anyway, thats not important. The thing is that the keys with "_" or "/" ends up surrounded with "-marks, and my web endpoint receiving JSON can't read it. Does anyone know how I can solve this? I use couchdb and need the _ in from of the attachments key.

EDIT: I am using it, I pass my dictionary to NSJSONSerialization, calling the function dataWithJSONObject:options:error:. I store what I get from that function in a NSData object, and set it as the http body in the request I make. Content-Type is application/json. I also set the Content-length etc. Here is the function that makes the HTTP request. `createDictionary` is the function above.

```
// Make a JSON object from the dictionary
NSError *err;
NSData* jsonRoom = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[room createDictionary]
                                                     options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                       error:&err];

// Set up the http POST request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _baseURL, @"/peters_hotell"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonRoom length]]
                          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonRoom];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonRoom);
// Fire the http POST request
//[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:callback];`
```

Right now the `sendRequest` call is commented out, but when I use it, the server can't accept the request.

This is the response from couchdb:

`Data: {
    error = badmatch;
    reason = false;
}`

When I leave the attachments part out of the dictionary, couch does not complain. Basically what I am trying to create is this JSON (inline attachment): http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments

Comment: Why do you 1. not read the documentation of `NSLog()` to find out what it does, 2. not read the official specification of JSON to know what it is before trying to use it, 3. assume that the description of `NSDictionary` is natively JSON?

Comment: are you getting BAD URL error

Comment: @H2CO3 - I've updated the post a little. I do not assume that the description of NSDictionary is valid JSON, but I assume what NSJSONSerialization returns is. Just forgot to metion that I use it.

Comment: @VishnuPrasath No, I am not. I don't know if you are familiar with couchdb, but I'll post the response I get above.

Comment: @kjelelokk uncomment the sendRequest and try to log the error if(err){NSLog(@"Error:%@",err);}

Comment: @VishnuPrasath I've already done it. The HTTP POST in it self does not seem to be the problem, it doesn't return any error. It is couchdb who returns an error, the one I posted above.

Comment: You are looking at the output of NSLog, as it displays an NSDictionary.  NSDictionary's `description` method places quotes around strings that contain blanks or "odd" characters -- has nothing to do with how the data is stored, or how it will be converted to JSON (where ALL strings are contained in quotes).

Comment: @kjelelokk i'm pretty sure because of request URL string have special characters and it have to be encoded.. i Too had same issue in one of my app.. but i used SBJson..\

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the information, should have checked that up sooner.

Comment: @kjelelokk: What makes you think that "_" and "/" are the problem?

Comment: @VishnuPrasath Is "_" one of these special characters? I'll try the encoding thing.

Comment: Put the whole thing into JSON first, then add the percent escapes.  You'll need to convert the JSON NSData to NSString to do this, though.

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but don't think that percent escapes are necessary for a HTTP POST ***body*** (unless CouchDB expects it that way).

Comment: @MartinR - Yep, I didn't look at the details of the request operation, and I always have to look up the specs in references anyway -- can't remember it all since I do HTTP only rarely.

Comment: @kjelelokk: According to your link to the CouchDB documentation, the POST request to create an inline attachment needs an "_id" parameter.

Comment: @HotLicks I figured it out. Turns out my data string wasn't valid base64 (which I knew, just didn't think it mattered), so couch refused it. Thanks for for the help! It led me to the answer.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but if I don't add one, couch will add one for me. Thanks anyway, I solved it. The data entry in the JSON had to be valid base64, didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, it's fairly easy to be distracted by an "abnormality" and think that that is the cause of a problem, when it's really something much more mundane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! It led me to the answer. As it turns out, my POST request was refused because my data entry wasn't valid base64, so couch refused it.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is that the keys [...] end up being surrounded with quotation marks, and my web endpoint receiving JSON can't read it.

No, it's the opposite: what you think is JSON isn't really JSON. JSON requires the keys to be quoted, it separates keys and values using colons (`:`) and not an equal sign, etc.

What you currently print out is the description of the `NSDictionary` object and it is not JSON. It's in the legacy NeXTSTEP-style property list format.

What you want to use is the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Comment: I am using it, I pass my dictionary to `NSJSONSerialization`, calling the function `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`. I store what I get from that function in a `NSData` object, and set it as the http body in the request I make. Content-Type is `application/json`. I also set the `Content-length` etc.

Comment: @kjelelokk - To see the real JSON, capture the NSData output from NSJSONSerialization, convert it to an NSString (`initWithData:jsonRoom encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` should do it) and NSLog the resulting NSString.

Comment: (PS: Unfortunately Apple doesn't supply APIs that read/write JSON as an NSString.  Other JSON libraries are nicer to use in this regard.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, it now logs it as JSON. The JSON is valid, only thing it does is that it turns `"content_type" : "text/plain"` into `"content_type" : "text\/plain"`. I think the JSON is ok, and so is the HTTP POST request it self, so the problem must be elsewhere. Thanks for the help figuring this out though.

Answer (score 1):

When you are posting the url and Json Object, before posting it to server encode the  URL string using the

> stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

or

> NSUTF8Encoding technique..

Comment: @kjelelokk - that isn't what he said.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
@implementation NSString (NSString_Extended)

- (NSString *)urlEncoded
{
    CFStringRef urlString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                NULL,
                                                                (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
    return [(NSString *)urlString autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've solved it. Just can't accept my own answer for a couple of days.